# Passing an argument

Tags: javascript

I was trying to build a to-do list app using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Task divs are assigned IDs upon their creation which correspond to the task object's index in an array like so:

```
    static addTaskToList(taskItem) {
     const ul = document.querySelector('.tasks-ul');

     const taskContainer = document.createElement('div');
     taskContainer.classList.add('task-container');

     const check = document.createElement('div');
     check.classList.add('task-checkbox');
     var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
     checkbox.type = "checkbox";
     checkbox.name = "name";
     checkbox.value = "value";
     checkbox.id = "id";
     check.appendChild(checkbox);

     taskContainer.appendChild(check);

     const taskContent = document.createElement('div'); 
     taskContent.classList.add('task-content');
     taskContent.setAttribute('id', `${taskItems.length - 1}`);

     const taskTitle = document.createElement('div');
     taskTitle.classList.add('task-title');
     taskTitle.innerText = `${taskItem.title}`;
     taskContent.appendChild(taskTitle);

     const taskDescription = document.createElement('div');
     taskDescription.classList.add('task-description', 'task-body');
     taskDescription.innerText = `${taskItem.description}`;
     taskContent.appendChild(taskDescription);

     const taskInfo = document.createElement('div');
     taskInfo.classList.add('task-info', 'task-body');

     const taskDueDate = document.createElement('div');
     taskDueDate.innerText = `${taskItem.dueDate}`;
     taskInfo.appendChild(taskDueDate);

     const taskPriority = document.createElement('div');
     taskPriority.innerText = `${taskItem.priority}`;
     taskInfo.appendChild(taskPriority);

     taskContent.appendChild(taskInfo);
     taskContainer.appendChild(taskContent);

     const li = document.createElement('li');
     li.appendChild(taskContainer);

    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.firstElementChild);     
}
```

The tasks are appended to the '#project-content' div in the HTML

```
   <section id="main">
    <div id="project-content">
      <div class="add-task">
          <button class="add-task-btn">+</button>
          <a href="#" class="add-task-link">Add task</a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </section>
   <section id="side-bar">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
   </section>
```

I used a modal to edit a task (it pops up when a task's title or description is clicked), but I couldn't figure out how to pass a task's ID to the update funcitons which get trigerred when the saveModalBtn is clicked.

```
document.getElementById('project-content').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const modal = document.getElementById('todo-modal');
  const i = e.target.parentElement.id;

  if(e.target.classList.contains('task-title') || e.target.classList.contains('task-description')) {
    displayController.populateModal(i); 
    displayController.openModal(modal);
  }
})

saveModalBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const index = ;

  store.updateTaskInStore(index);
  displayController.updateTaskInUI(index);
});
```

Comment: Hey @Dagem, have you tried editing the task directly from the array?

Comment: Hey @BeniTrainor, thanks for your msg, please see the edited question

Comment: Could you post the HTML you're using? From this code alone I can't tell. For example, why are you adding a single event listener to a `taskEditBtn`. Wouldn't you need one edit button for each task?

Comment: Kindly refer to the new edit

Comment: Why don't you include the `id` somewhere in the modal? Modify `displayController.populateModal(i)` so that the `id` is added in the HTML as non-editable text. And then in the `saveModalBtn` event listener you can get the value from the HTML.

Comment: right, that did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All your tasks in the list should have some IDs. I would suggest not removing the task from the UI and the array. Instead update the UI and the array after the task is edited in the modal using its ID.

I would recommend a few easy to follow todo list tutorials. Using [React library](https://reactjs.org) will help you a lot. Todo list is usually a starter tutorial into the React world.

**How to build a Todo List App with JavaScript** (https://freshman.tech/todo-list/)

**How to Code A Better To-Do List - Tutorial** (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7FaYfuwu70)

**Learn React In 30 Minutes** (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQAHSlTtcmY)

Comment: Thanks for your msg. Please see the edited question